# Jquery Click Function (Depending on which instance of MYSQL Result div is clicked)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have a MYSQL query loop to fetch the list of available items in my table. I am putting my results into divs like so:

```
<?php $myStats = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM packages, packages_benefits WHERE packages.package_id = packages_benefits.package_id AND packages.status = 'Active'");
    if ($myStats->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $myStats->fetch_assoc()) { 

    echo '<div class="advertise_unit">';
    echo '<div class="advertise_unit_u">';

    echo '<h10>'.$row['name'].'</h10>';

    echo '<div class="button_p">Buy Now</div>';

    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="description_contain"><li>'.$row['b_1'].'</li></div>';
    echo '<div class="description_contain"><li>'.$row['b_2'].'</li></div>';
    echo '<div class="description_contain"><li>'.$row['b_3'].'</li></div>';
    echo '<div class="description_contain"><li>'.$row['b_4'].'</li></div>';


    echo '<div class="price_tag"><h4>£'.$row['price'].'</h4></div>';
    echo '</div>';

    } } ?>
```

This produces a result like so:

```
Wrapped In Div ($row['name'] = Result 1 ).      Wrapped In Div($row['name'] = Result 2) .      Wrapped In Div ($row['name'] = Result 3)
```

Next, Depending on which `button_p div` the user clicks on, I want to run my jquery script to retrieve/insert the corresponding value of that divs $row['name'] into my form select field. Bearing in mind each value will be different - depending on the div that was clicked.

```
<div id="registration" style="display:none; padding:5.5em; text-align: left;">
<?php include 'assets/registration.php';?>
</div>
<script>
    $('.button_p').click(function(){
    $("#ad_type select").val($row['name'] value of DIV CLICKED SHOULD GO HERE);
    $('#registration').show(150);
    $('html, body').scrollTop($('#registration').offset().top);
    return false; // Please put the return false; at the end.
}); 
</script>
```

Contents of page registration.php:

```
select name="Advert Type" id="ad_type" class="edit">
  <option value="Deluxe">Deluxe</option>
  <option value="Premium">Premium</option>
  <option value="Basic">Basic</option>
</select>
```

Please can someone show me how to do what It is I am  trying to achieve. 
Essentially, if you imagine there are 3 results being displayed. 
All with a different value for $row['name'].

```
Div<div class="button_p"></div>
$row['name'] = 1 .

Div<div class="button_p"></div>
$row['name'] = 2 .

Div<div class="button_p"></div>
$row['name'] = 3 .
```

For Whichever button_p div the user clicks on for each div - I want to retrieve the corresponding value of $row['name'] for that div and enter it into my select field using jquery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First issue, `$("#ad_type select")`  The select is the `#ad_type` so either that needs to be `select#ad_type` or just `#ad_type`

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *DIV CLICKED VALUE*. Please clarify what value you're looking for in your HTML. The DIV element does not have a Value attribute. Did you mean class? ID? Content?

Comment: @Twisty have amended that section. So if the user clicks button_p then the value of $row['name'] for that div is what i am wanting to retrieve.

Comment: @M.Obren which Row are you trying to get the value from? How do you know which was clicked? Which part of it contains the *Value*

Comment: @Twisty i don't know which div was clicked, hence my question. How can i find out. Also imagine there are 3 results, and each of these has a different value for $row['name']. Depending on which instance of button_p the user clicks for each result i want to retrieve the corresponding $row['name'] value of that result

Comment: @Twisty please see question update clarifying in greater detail

Comment: @M.Obren please clarify *my input field *. I do not see ANY Input fields.

Comment: @Twisty my apologies select field. not input. Question updateds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by replacing your  selector by **#ad_type** only and get the value of $raw['name'] of the clicked div.

```
<script>
    $('.button_p').click(function(){
    $("#ad_type").val($(this).parent('.advertise_unit_u').find('h10').html());
    $('#registration').show(150);
    $('html, body').scrollTop($('#registration').offset().top);
    return false; // Please put the return false; at the end.
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Genius this worked perfect. I accepted this answer because it was the simplest solution and most easily adaptable with my pre-existing code. Thanks